# How I can update changes on remote git repository?

Tags: git, commit, git-push, git-clone, git-remote

I finished to commit and push changes on remote git repository but when I view remote repository's files, these are outdated. I'm using Git Bash.

[View image](http://tinypic.com/r/2o5jk/6)

The red text are changes made in repositories clones. These changes aren't reflected in the original repository's physical file

How I can do to reflect the changes?

Comment: Did your push succeed? The result of your commands might be useful.

Comment: Is strange...When clone the server repository I can get last changes committed. But when I view the files in the server repository it hasn't changes...I use Egit to push changes...Everything seemed right

Comment: Can you publish your picture with an address ending with '.png'? I will be able to import it in your question for you. But I can't see tinypic.com at work (blocked)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assumed that you are pushing to a branch that the remote currently checking out. Because it seems like a non-bare repository, and have files checking out in your description.

I made some simple tests to simulate such push, and the following message displayed:

```
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
```

If you're sure you do the push successfully(that will be reject at default), then you have to execute following at the remote repository.

```
git reset --hard
```

Comment: Thanks for helping =). My error was to create the server repository as normal repository and not as bare repository. I didn't know at about bare repository...By the way in the bare repository the files are stored in binary? I don't see a working directory

Comment: There are just commit objects in the bare repository, generally you won't never checkout any files on the remote repository, its only job is to hold the commits. If you want to deploy it into a centralized development environment or something on every push, maybe you can add a hook in the bare repository to do this for you. Besides you will do it in hook post-update or post-receive, depends on your git version.